# Vedana: does it include feeling sleepy, dizzy, alert…

Tags: mindfulness, terminology

I am a (somewhat lackadaisical) follower of S.N. Goenka's meditation teachings.  After a couple of 10-day retreats and reading some articles such as this: http://www.vridhamma.org/Why-Vedana-and-What-is-Vedana I'm still not sure how to regard sensations that at least in Western terms are not simple sensory input, but which also do not imply any attachment or revulsion —  feelings like the ones above, or hunger, fatigue  and so on. Are those vedana, and hence proper objects of mindfulness?

Answer (score 1):

> **I'm still not sure how to regard sensations that at least in Western terms are not simple sensory input**

In the Pali suttas, 'vedana' refer to: (i) *pleasant*; (ii) *unpleasant* &; (iii) *neither-pleasant-nor-unpleasant* feelings that occur with sense impressions.

When the mind lacks mindfulness-&-wisdom, pleasant feelings give rise to the defilement/urge of greed/lust/love; unpleasant feelings give rise to the defilement/urge of hatred/anger/irritation; and neither feeling can give rise to confusion.

> **but which also do not imply any attachment or revulsion**

Vedana/feelings are not attachment or revulsion. For example, if you break your leg, that is an unpleasant feeling. The revulsion (hatred) or attachment is a separate matter.

> **hunger, fatigue and so on.**

Hunger begins with an unpleasant/painful feeling but, ordinarily, quickly gives rise craving. You should try to separate the painful feeling from the craving. Feeling/vedana is not an 'urge' & not 'thinking'. Feeling is the mere painful sensation.

Fatigue is not a vedana. It is a lack of energy, either related to exhaustion of the physical body or defilements of the mind weighing down the mind. Fatigue is classed as a 'hindrance' ('[nivarana](https://suttacentral.net/define/n%C4%ABvara%E1%B9%87a)') rather than a 'vedana' ('feeling').

Thus hunger is a proper object of mindfulness, where the meditator is vigilant towards & subdues craving & excitement towards food; thus attentive only to the painful stomach sensation.

Fatigue is a difficult & subtle object of mindfulness; unless one is a very skilled meditator. Generally, if fatigue arises, the meditator should focus on their physical posture; or change posture to standing or walking; or otherwise have some rest and sleep in bed. Refer to this [link](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nyanaponika/wheel026.html#sloth) about 'sloth & torpor'.

> *Bhikkhus, dependent on the eye and forms, eye-consciousness arises; the meeting of the three is contact; with contact as condition there
>   arises a feeling felt as pleasant or painful or
>   neither-painful-nor-pleasant. When one is touched by a **pleasant
>   feeling**, if one delights in it, welcomes it, and remains holding to
>   it, then the underlying tendency to lust lies within one. When one is
>   touched by a **painful feeling**, if one sorrows, grieves and laments,
>   weeps beating one’s breast and becomes distraught, then the underlying
>   tendency to aversion lies within one. When one is touched by a
>   **neither-painful-nor-pleasant feeling**, if one does not understand as it
>   actually is the origination, the disappearance, the gratification, the
>   danger, and the escape in regard to that feeling, then the underlying
>   tendency to ignorance lies within one. Bhikkhus, that one shall here
>   and now make an end of suffering without abandoning the underlying
>   tendency to lust for **pleasant feeling**, without abolishing the
>   underlying tendency to aversion towards **painful feeling**, without
>   extirpating the underlying tendency to ignorance in regard to
>   **neither-painful-nor-pleasant feeling**, without abandoning ignorance and
>   arousing true knowledge—this is impossible. [MN 148](https://suttacentral.net/en/mn148)*

Answer (score -1):

> Are those vedana, and hence proper objects of mindfulness?>

Yes. Feeling and sensations are conjoined hence not easy to separate. In that case been aware of all feelings and sensation is Vipassana meditation.